# Check affected rows before commit()

Tags: php, transactions, mysqli, rollback

Quick question that I can't seem to find an answer for.

Is there any way to check how many rows will be affected BEFORE committing the query?

```
$conn->autocommit(FALSE);
$conn->begin_transaction();
$conn->query($insert_query);
if(affected_rows_of_query == 0)
 -> Nothing happened
if(affected_rows_of_query == 1)
 -> Only one record will be updated -> Success!
 $conn->commit();
else
 ->in any other case, rollback
 $conn->rollback();
```

This will be used when updating one clients info. Because I know only one clients info should be updated, is there any way to check that not many rows would be affected by the query?

Comment: Easy. Just download and install Free Time Machine client PHP library.

Answer (score 0):

I feel ashamed.......

I was using a switch for checking this. And since the affected_rows affects NO ROWS, I got 0 when checking later.

solved by:

```
$affected = $conn->affected_rows;
switch($affected)
{
  case 0: //nothing
  break;
  case 1: //OK
  echo "Successfully updated 1 client row"
  break;
  default: $conn->rollback();
  echo "Tried to update " . $affected . " rows. Query rolled back"
  break;
```